# Run a Python project in Eclipse as root

Tags: python, eclipse, root, sudo, gksudo

I use Eclipse as my IDE, and when I run my application I wish the application itself to run as root. My program currently checks if it is root, and if not it restarts itself with `gksudo`. The output, however, isn't written to the console. I can't use `sudo`, since it doesn't give me a graphical prompt. (While my program is CLI, Eclipse doesn't permit console interaction afaict)

What's the "right" way to be elevating my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restrictive execution dominates. I believe that Eclipse does permit console interaction, but a quick and dirty, brute force approach would be to use suid if you're not concerned about security. Or throw up your own graphical prompt in Tkinter/other and use a bit of [Expect magic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pexpect/) to spawn and respond to the sudo process. Careful with these, however :)

Answer (score 3):

It may not be an ideal solution, but the rare times that I need this same functionality I end up just running Eclipse as root.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to create a runner with external tools pointing to '/sur/bin/sudo' and pointing to variable ${resource_loc}
Run -> External tools -> External Tools Configuration
The below link will guide you on creating a external runner,

http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-97_standalone_ets.htm

To run,
Click on the main python file
Run -> External tools -> {choose your runner}

This will serve your purpose.